# Using python, how do I replace single backslash characters in a string with double backslash characters?

Tags: python

I have written a python application that requires a Microsoft Windows user on a Windows 10 system to enter a path string, which I then need to store in a MySQL database.  The user enters their path as C:\aaa\bbb\ccc and I capture it in a string.  Before I can save it as a MySQL text field value, I need to somehow convert `C:\aaa\bbb\ccc` into `C:\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc`

```
path = r"C:\aaa\bbb\ccc"
```

How do I convert the single backslash characters in the "path" result represented by this line of code to double backslash characters in python?

Before you answer... I know what an escape character is and what it is used for in Python.  It does not change my question, as a Windows path is expressed without consideration to Python... The user is going to input backslash characters and I need to deal with them.  Someone has to have figured this out, I'm just looking for the answer.

Comment: Have you tried something like `path.replace(r'\', r'\\')`? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: (mind, the fact that Python _prints_ a path with double backslashes doesn't mean the path _actually has_ double backslashes -- `'\\'` is _exactly the same string_ as `r'\'`, so there's nothing to do to convert between them; they're already identical)

Comment: This sounds like you're building SQL statements with string formatting. Don't do that - use parameterized queries. Trying to build SQL through string formatting has all kinds of pitfalls that won't be immediately obvious to a newbie, and many of those pitfalls have catastrophic security consequences.

Comment: Also, what user2357112 says is spot on. You should **never** attempt to escape values for use in SQL yourself -- let your DB-API implementation take care of that for you via use of bound parameters, keeping the data and the query or DDL out-of-band from each other. Even for databases that have poorly-designed wire formats that don't keep the query text and the data completely separate, making the database connector library responsible for escaping means there's just one place to fix it if there's a bug, instead of every application using that database needing to be patched.

Comment: I'm not so sure that the OP is trying to build SQL statements, so much as store a string in a DB text or char field. Have you tried to manipulate the string by displaying, seeing what you have, and then using .replace() to create a suitable string that will translate into the network path?